# "Find in files" instead of "Find" Invoked in Visual Studio 2012 on SQL type files

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When editing .sql files in Visual Studio 2012, hitting Ctrl-F brings up the "Find in Files" dialog instead of just simple "Find". Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this Microsoft Connect article](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759133/attempting-to-open-the-quick-find-dialog-when-a-sql-file-has-focus-opens-the-find-in-files-dialog), it has been fixed in SQL Server Data Tools, you can update it from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015).